# why does the .then run before the resolve function here?

Tags: javascript

I have this block of code, and the post works perfectly fine if i comment out the .then part, but if i leave it in, the post will not go through. How might I go about fixing this?

```
      axios.post('http://localhost:5000/exercises/add', exercise)
                .then(res => console.log(res.data))
                .then(window.location.href = '/')
                .catch(err => console.log(err))
```

Comment: Because you have a statement there.. It will get executed beforehand.. Wrap it in a function like `then(function(){window.location.href='/';})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 `then` for some reason which is not needed. Try combining the two together

```js
axios.post('http://localhost:5000/exercises/add', exercise)
  .then(res => {
    console.log(res.data)
    window.location.href = '/'
  })
  .catch(err => console.log(err))
```

Answer (score 4):

`window.location.href = '/'` **isn't a function**

It gets evaluated **immediately** and the result is passed to `then()` (since the result isn't a function, this is useless).

Do what you did on the previous line:

```
  axios.post('http://localhost:5000/exercises/add', exercise)
        .then(res => console.log(res.data))
        .then(log_result => (window.location.href = '/'))
        .catch(err => console.log(err))
```

Better yet, since you aren't getting a promise back from `console.log`, just have the one `then()`:

```
  axios.post('http://localhost:5000/exercises/add', exercise)
        .then(res => {
            console.log(res.data);
            window.location.href = '/';
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err))
```